# Definite integration by parts of $f(x)/x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This is probably a very (very) stupid question but reading a certain paper I have come upon the following

$$
\int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t} dt = f(x) \log(x)  - \int_0^x f'(t)\log(t)dt
$$

I get we are integrating by parts but what happens to the definite integral in the first term? Shouldn't we have something like

$$
\int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t} dt = \big(f(x) \log(x)  - \int f'(t)\log(t)dt \big)_0^x
$$

what am I missing? The function $f$ has the following singular expansion

$$
f(x) = F_0 + F_1 X + F_2 X^2 + F_3X^3 + O(X^4)
$$

where $X = \sqrt{1 - x/\rho}$ for $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F_i$ are non-zero.

Comment: The first term on the RHS should definitely not be in terms of $t$ (as written). Perhaps the function $f$ has sufficient condiitons so that the $f(0)\log(0)$ term goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$ and we're left with the $f(x) \log(x)$ term only after evaluating?

Comment: The only "stupid" question is the one that is never asked.

Comment: Supplementing the first comment, note that $$\int_{\epsilon}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=f(x)\log x-f(\epsilon)\log(\epsilon)-\int_{\epsilon}^{x}f'(t)\log t\,\mathrm{d}t$$ and then the equality in question will hold if $f(\epsilon)\log(\epsilon)\to0$ as $\epsilon\to0$. Adding the context (such as providing a reference to the actual paper) might also help to tell more about your question.

Comment: PhysicsMathsLove Thanks, that was a typo.

@SangchulLee Im afraid it doesnt' hold, $f(0) \neq 0$. The paper is the following:
[link](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-02/S0894-0347-08-00624-3/). The equation in question is on page 321

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Thanks that was a typo, the $f$ in question has a singular expansion of the form $F_0 + F_1 X + F_2 X^2 + F_3X^3 + O(X^4)$ where $X = \sqrt{1 - x/\rho}$. So I do not see the sufficient conditions.

Comment: If $f(0) \neq 0$, then the integral is divergent and there is nothing else to say about it. This makes me think that it is supposed $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Crostul, thats what I thought but I really don't see $f(0) =0$ .

Comment: I checked the [preprint version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501269.pdf) and I am pretty sure that $F(0)=0$, since $F(x)/x=C'(x)$ is the derivative of an analytic function around $x=0$. Note that the singular singular expansion that you mentioned holds around $x=\rho$, and so, $F_0=F(\rho)$ need not correspond to the value of $F(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

As people pointed out in the comments we have $F(x) = xC'(x)$ where $C$ is analytic function at $0$. Thus, one has

$$
\lim_x F(x) log(x) = \lim_x xC'(x)log(x) 
$$

Wich goes to $0$ since $xlog(x)$ goes to $0$.